# How to get rid of "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jprofiler

I'm taking multipart file in rest input and validating some properties of file after which I'm uploading a multipart file to different service using **file.getResource()**

```
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        **body.add("model", file.getResource());**
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
}
```

I need to pass the entire file to a downstream system while doing so,
JVM memory is getting increased exorbitantly and it is not freeing up the space for a very long time meanwhile multiple such operations are utilizing the entire heap space.

I could increase the max heap size using command line option to java, but that doesn't seems to be a feasible solution going forward.

I noticed via JProfiler that it takes a lot space in heap memory and the main problem is that it doesn't freeing up the space after execution of that api.

I'm sharing screenshot of JProfiler too. You can see that the graph is not coming down as its not emptying the space.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycrRJ.png)

I'm looking for a solution where I can take the file in input and upload to the downstream application while utilizing very minimum heap space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java isn't lying to you. Memory is full. "Extending heap size dynamically" is not some voodoo magic that would fix that. The proper solution is to stream large data instead of the process of 'read ALL the data, store it in memory, edit the data (all of it) in memory, and stream it out again'. Instead fo: "read a chunk of data, process it, stream it out again. Read the next chunk, etc".

Comment: It's hard to guess what exactly is using the memory from your description and the screenshot alone (which is just stating that memory is being used) so I assume it's the file contents in which case there are 2 basic strategies: 1) if you're dealing with a lot of smaller files make sure the memory can be garbage collected when you're done (use JProfiler to find out what's preventing GC if you're facing problems with that) and 2) as rswitserloot suggested, for large files use a streaming approach - maybe mixed with memory mapping if required.

Comment: I have edited my question to add more details. Could you please help how can I partially stream the file and upload to downstream system.

Comment: So does it fail after the first request? You can configure JVM to create a HeapDump upon OOM and store it in the file so that you could see which objects are allocated and not released. Maybe the file is indeed just too big, what is the size of the file you're trying to upload to server?

Comment: my file size is 70 MB . but this can go till 500 MB . For 70 MB file upload JVM is consuming around 400-600 MB of heap space . If max heap space is set to 500 MB , application goes down when I upload the file . If max heap size is around 2GB then 4-5 concurrent file uploads will bring down the application